# Flink Dataset API not compatible with scala case classes

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am learning Flink with the scala API and I do not quite understand why do I get at task serialization error.

I am using the DatasetAPI and trying to simply convert the following into scala case classes.

```
    case class User(name: String, country: String, city: String)

    val userDataSet: DataSet[String] = env.fromCollection(List(
      "Peter,Germany,Berlin",
      "James,UK,London",
      "Tom,America,NewYork"
    ))
```

If I try to map it to case classes, I get the following error:

```
    val sultSet = userDataSet.map {
      text =>
        val fieldArr: Array[String] = text.split(",")
        User(fieldArr(0), fieldArr(1), fieldArr(2))
    }
    sultSet.print()
```

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.api.common.InvalidProgramException: Task not serializable

Why is this the case? Case classes in scala extend serializable and should not be an issue. Is this related to this ticket?

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-16969

```
    val sultSet1 = userDataSet.map {
      text =>
        lazy val fieldArr: Array[String] = text.split(",")
        Tuple3(fieldArr(0), fieldArr(1), fieldArr(2))
    }
```

This works just fine, however, it is not clear why one cannot use case classes.

Comment: Try moving the `case class` outside of whatever `class` this code resides in. I.e. if it is in `Main` move the `case class` outside of `Main`

Comment: Ah. Yes that worked. Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that Flink's DataSet API is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. You should use either the Table API or the DataStream API